# Socket Closed exception being thrown on accept() call

Tags: java, sockets, port

I have looked for a solution, but I cannot find one yet. I'm trying to program a socket lock so only one instance of my program can run at a time, but I am getting a socket closed exception. Here's my SocketCode code

```
package utilities;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;

import utilities.enums.ClientType;

public class SocketLocker {
    private final int PORT;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket clientSocket;

    public SocketLocker(ClientType cType) {
        serverSocket = null;
        clientSocket = null;
        switch (cType)
            {
            case PRODUCER:
                PORT = 7856;
                break;
            case CONSUMER:
                PORT = 7857;
                break;
            default:
                PORT = 7859;
            }
    }

    public boolean getLock() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT,1);
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: log event
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void releaseLock() {
        try {
            if (clientSocket != null)
                clientSocket.close();
            if (serverSocket != null)
                serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: Log event

        }
    }
}
```

And here's my unit test code which is what I'm running to get the exception:

```
package utilities;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import utilities.enums.ClientType;

public class SocketLockerTest {

    private SocketLocker producerLocker;
    private SocketLocker consumerLocker;

    @Before
    public void start() {
        producerLocker = new SocketLocker(ClientType.PRODUCER);
        consumerLocker = new SocketLocker(ClientType.CONSUMER);
    }

    @Test(timeout = 10000)
    public void lockProducer() {
        assertTrue(producerLocker.getLock());
    }

    @Test(timeout = 10000)
    public void lockConsumer() {
        assertTrue(consumerLocker.getLock());
    }

    @Test(timeout = 10000)
    public void lockProducerTwice() {
        producerLocker.getLock();
        assertFalse(producerLocker.getLock());
    }

    @Test(timeout = 10000)
    public void lockSeparately() {
        producerLocker.getLock();
        assertTrue(consumerLocker.getLock());
    }

    @Test(timeout = 10000)
    public void lockProdcuerSeparateObject(){
        producerLocker.getLock();
        assertFalse(new SocketLocker(ClientType.PRODUCER).getLock());
    }

    @After
    public void finish() {
        producerLocker.releaseLock();
        consumerLocker.releaseLock();
    }
}
```

And here's the exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at utilities.SocketLocker.getLock(SocketLocker.java:34)
    at utilities.SocketLockerTest.lockProducer(SocketLockerTest.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$1.run(FailOnTimeout.java:28)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the purpose of the server socket is only to prevent two instances running at once, there is no point in accepting a connection on it at all. Just remove the client socket variable and the accept() call. You have implemented not a lock but in effect a deadlock.

Comment: @matheszabi It is not a good answer *why?* Statements like that are 100% useless to anybody. Similarly, unexplained downvotes are basically just site vandalism. In actual fact the answer corrects not only the testing problem cited by the OP but a *major* design flaw in his application. If you don't understand that you should be asking questions. You're talking when you should be listening.

Comment: @matheszabi I thought this was a great answer. This showed me what my problem was, and it guided me in the right direction to get the solution.

Comment: @ReidMac Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

your test fails on timeout. when you call

```
 @Test(timeout = 10000)
    public void lockProducer() {
        assertTrue(producerLocker.getLock());
    }
```

what happens it that you open a server socket on the specified port, and then you wait for a connection to enter.

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT,1);
clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

so, your code will wait on accept until timeout because you didn't initiate a connection attempt.